# crashlytics beta add build flavors

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I'm using Crashlytics beta for our beta distribution using fastlane and for both iOS and Android I get the same issue.

1. I'm unable to upload different flavors, only the last updated flavor is visible in the app list.
2. I'm unable to see the previous builds, only the most recent one.

Is there a way to add flavors/build variants for iOS and Android. And where can I see the list of previous uploads?

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. If I understand correctly, when you upload a new build flavor, the other build flavors disappear from your app list. This is highly unusual. Please drop us a line at support(at)fabric(dot)io and we can dig into the problem there.

Comment: I have been having this issue since the beginning. Works fine on iOS android only allowing .debug and standard app package name

Answer (score 0):

Set `ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId` to `true` in you build.gradle file.